# Getting error while installing python3-pip in linux stating python3-pip not installed

Tags: python-3.x

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate

Try by adding the universe repository in your local.

Command - `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Run the above universe repository command.
After running successfully update the system by the given command below

Command - `sudo apt update`

After update try to run the below command.

Command - `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: You have not shown the error though. I guess you just posted the instructions you followed.

Comment: what is the error ?  where are you stuck ?

Comment: Make sure to include an actual question in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install python3-pip`